# Persisting nested structs in golang

Tags: json, pointers, go, struct

I want to add persistence and initialize from json.
I'm trying to save/load nested structs and getting "fatal error: stack overflow".

As I understand, the reason is that both parent and child structs have pointers to each other and json library is going into loops. I need pointer to Parent since need access it from the child.

I understand this is common issue, what is the best way to address it?

```
type Mcloud struct {
    Projects map[string]*Project `json:"Projects"`
    Workdir  string
}

type Project struct {
    Name     string
    Networks map[string]Network
    Parent   *Mcloud
    TFC      TFConf
}

func newMcloud() *Mcloud {
    mc := &Mcloud{
        Projects: make(map[string]*Project),
        Workdir:  defaultWorkDir,
    }
    mc.load(statefile)

    return mc
}


func (mc *Mcloud) addProject(n string) {
    mc.Projects[n] = &Project{
        Name:     n,
        Networks: make(map[string]Network),
        Parent:   mc,
    }
    mc.Projects[n].addTFConf()
}

//save saves state to statefile
func (mc *Mcloud) save(f string) (err error) {
    if jsonState, err := json.Marshal(mc); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Was not able to marshal")
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        if err := ioutil.WriteFile(f, jsonState, 0666); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Was not able to write state to", f, "!")
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Save function saves: \n", mc, "to file ", f)
    }

    return err
}

func (mc *Mcloud) load(f string) (err error) {
    var bytestate []byte

    if bytestate, err = ioutil.ReadFile(f); err == nil {
        err = json.Unmarshal(bytestate, &mc)
    }

    return err
}
```

Getting

> runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit fatal error:
>   stack overflow
>
> runtime stack: runtime.throw(0x149cdfe, 0xe)
>           /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:608 +0x72 runtime.newstack()
>           /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/runtime/stack.go:1008 +0x729 runtime.morestack()
>           /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:429 +0x8f
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: runtime.heapBitsSetType(0xc042a7df20, 0x60,
>   0x60, 0x1486e60)
>           /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/runtime/mbitmap.go:911 +0xa30 fp=0xc02243c388 sp=0xc02243c380 pc=0x1016cd0 runtime.mallocgc(0x60, 0x1486e60, 0x1, 0x0)
>           /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:933 +0x540 fp=0xc02243c428 sp=0xc02243c388 pc=0x100d4f0 runtime.newobject(0x1486e60, 0x0)
>           /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.1/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:1032 +0x38 fp=0xc02243c458 sp=0xc02243c428 pc=0x100db28 reflect.mapiterinit(0x14206a0, 0xc00009d830, 0x0)

Comment: This may not be related, but in your `load` method, you are passing a pointer to a pointer to `json.Unmarshal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to tell `encoding/json` to skip the parent field, you can do that with the `json:"-"` tag.

Then during unmarshaling, after you've loaded all of a parent's children you loop over the children and set their parent, you can do this as part of the unamrshaling process by implementing the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface.

```
type Mcloud struct {
    Projects map[string]*Project `json:"Projects"`
    Workdir  string
}

type Project struct {
    Name     string
    Networks map[string]Network
    Parent   *Mcloud `json:"-"` // ignore on un/marshal
    TFC      TFConf
}

func (m *Mcloud) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type tmp Mcloud
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, (*tmp)(m)); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // set Parent of all projects
    for _, p := range m.Projects {
        p.Parent = m
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: @mkoptiva thanks! You made my day! 
Could you please suggest where to ready about  the following expression "(*tmp)(m)" , I don't understand why not working by passing "m" object directly to Unmarshal()  ?

Comment: @nixlike If you pass `m` directly to `json.Unmarshal` it will again call `m.UnmarshalJSON` method and so on until you get stack overflow. `type tmp Mcloud` creates a new type called `tmp` that has the same structure as `Mcloud` but none of its methods, so `tmp` does not have `UnmarshalJSON` for example, and therefore it is safe to pass it to `json.Unmarshal`. And because the two types have the same structure you can convert between them. `(*tmp)(m)` is an expression that converts `m`'s type (`*Mcloud`) to `*tmp`.

Comment: Same kind of expression as `[]byte("hello world")`, converting a `string` literal to `[]byte`.